# Search for string OR string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find `<META content="http.*jpg` OR `content="http.*png` using regex (.NET) in a block of text. So far I've tried the following without success:

```
<META content="http.*jpg|content="http.*png
<META content="http.*jpg | content="http.*png
(<META content="http.*jpg|content="http.*png)
(<META content="http.*jpg | content="http.*png)
```

If I only search for `<META content="http.*jpg` it finds it but if I use the bar `|` like in the examples above I get nothing.

Need some help please.

Comment: the 3rd form you tried should do the trick. You get any errors?

Comment: if possible add some part of the text using blockquote

Comment: Your first and third expressions work fine ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQ1iA8/1)). There must be something you are doing in the API calls that make it not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(<META content="http.*jpg)|(content="http.*png)
```

Explanation:

- you have to specify regex which part to give preference on `|` operator.. which can be done by using paranthesis

Comment: the second condition of OP has `png` suffix